# The numerical solution cannot be obtained by solving the Trigonometric functions equation under known conditions?

Tags: equation-solving

```
In[456]:= Clear["Global`*"]
Reduce[{TrigExpand[Sin[a - b]] == 1/3, Cos[a] Sin[b] == 1/6, 
  t == TrigExpand[Cos[2 a + 2 b]]}, t]

Out[457]= 
Sin[a] != 0 && Cos[b] == Csc[a]/2 && Sin[b] != 0 && 
 Cos[a] == Csc[b]/6 && 
 t == 1/18 (-11 + 18 Cos[a]^2 Cos[b]^2 + 18 Sin[a]^2 Sin[b]^2)
```

The solution to this equation is 1/9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eliminate `{a,b}`.

```
Reduce[{TrigExpand[Sin[a - b]] == 1/3, Cos[a] Sin[b] == 1/6, 
  t == TrigExpand[Cos[2 a + 2 b]]}, t, {a, b}]
```

> `t == 1/9`.

Answer (score 4):

> the key to this equation is 1/9

How about using Solve instead?

```
sol=Solve[{TrigExpand[Sin[a-b]]==1/3,Cos[a] Sin[b]==1/6,t==TrigExpand[Cos[2 a+2 b]]},{t,a,b}];
t/.sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Two remarks:

---

`Reduce` can simplify this without `TrigExpand`.

```
Reduce[{Sin[a - b] == 1/3 && Cos[a] Sin[b] == 1/6 && 
   t == Cos[2 a + 2 b]}, t, {a, b}]
```

> t == 1/9

---

**Using `Eliminate`:**

```
Eliminate[
   TrigExpand /@ {Sin[a - b] == 1/3, Cos[a] Sin[b] == 1/6 , 
     t == Cos[2 a + 2 b]}, {a, b}] // Quiet
```

> 9 t == 1